# Foreach insert query the best way

Tags: php

Hi i've got this code which works fine but I think it uses a lot of server resources because execute a query to the database for each user id stored in a group, is there any way to solve this problem? Also how can I use prepared statement?

```
$event_start_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($new_start_date));
    $notification = "Nuovo evento <span class='text-warning'><strong>$event_title</strong></span> inizia il $event_start_date";
    $notification_status = "0";
    $notification_category= "events";


    $sql = "SELECT user_join_id FROM user_group_join WHERE group_join_id='$event_group'";

    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $datas= array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $datas[]= $row;

        }

    }

    foreach($datas as $data) {

    $id_cliente = $data['user_join_id'];

    $event_notification = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO user_notifications (notification_sent_by, notification_sent_to, notification_message, notification_time, notification_status, notification_category, notification_category_id) VALUES(?,?,?,now(),?,?,?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($event_notification, 'iisisi', $userid, $id_cliente, $notification, $notification_status, $notification_category, $event_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($event_notification);
    mysqli_stmt_close($event_notification);

    }
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know where you are getting the value for `$event_group` from but it bothers me that you go through the trouble of binding prepared statements for the INSERT but not the SELECT.

Comment: Also, more on topic, do you know that this code is running sub-optimally or are you guessing it is?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you prepare the statement, use it, and then close it every step of the loop. That's a lot of wasted effort.

Prepare once, use for the loop, then close at the end.

```
$event_notification = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO user_notifications (notification_sent_by, notification_sent_to, notification_message, notification_time, notification_status, notification_category, notification_category_id) VALUES(?,?,?,now(),?,?,?)");
foreach($datas as $data) {
    $id_cliente = $data['user_join_id'];
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($event_notification, 'iisisi', $userid, $id_cliente, $notification, $notification_status, $notification_category, $event_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($event_notification);
}
mysqli_stmt_close($event_notification);
```

I would expect that to be a heck of a lot faster.

I am no expert with mysqli and prepared statements but I am pretty sure you can bind all the data into a huge array and do the interest in one hit.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512498/mysqli-multiple-row-insert-simple-multi-insert-query) suggests that to me, anyway. Given you already built the big array, you should be able to use it without `foreach` to break it back up. That might be even faster still.